# Doing an action after a set delay in java

Tags: java, timer, delay, actionlistener, actionevent

**Edit: Got it to work. My problem was I was using cmd to compile which exited the vm before the delay ended. Switched to jGrasp and the program worked as intended. Next I need to learn how to actually make a java applet to properly run on my computer. Thanks for your help everyone**

I'm trying to set an alarm of sorts using java. I'd like to open a webpage after a set delay. The code below compiles and runs without errors or warnings but running the code does nothing. Just starts and stops the program. I have a feeling the issue arises from how I catch the exceptions but I'm not sure. I also am a little lost on what the actionPerformed() method does. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class YtAlarmTest
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"; 
        int delay = 1000;
        ActionListener task = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
            {   
                try
                {
                    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
                    {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url));
                    }
                }
                catch (URISyntaxException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("exception");
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("exceptio");
                }
            }
        };
        new Timer(delay, task).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `main` method exits (the VM) after setting up the timer, so it gets never called....

Comment: do you want to open browser repeatedly with some delay, an I correct

Comment: Your code works fine for me, but you could consider also catching "Exception" since Desktop.getDesktop() can throw an unchecked exception (HeadlessException which is an UnsupportedOperaitonException).

Comment: You never initialise the EDT, so the JVM will terminate when it exists the `main` method. Maybe consider using `java.util.Timer` instead

Comment: @PramodYadav No just once

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay I'll give that class a shot and see if anything changes